# The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to execute a query using a LocalTime parameter.

My query in the jpa repository (note that I have manually hardcoded 15:30 just as a test and the query works fine if I only have that hardcoded value):

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Entity b WHERE b.from = '15:30' AND b.to =:to")
public List<Entity> getByParams(@Param("to") LocalTime to);
```

Where `from` and `to` in my entity are defined as:

```
@Column(name = "name1", columnDefinition = "TIME")
private LocalTime from;
@Column(name = "name2", columnDefinition = "TIME")
private LocalTime to;
```

But when executing the method I get `The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the equal to operator`. I have already looked up the error and this problem was supposed to be resolved by adding the parameter to the db url `sendTimeAsDateTime=false`

But I have already done that and it did not fix the problem:

`url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;database=xxx;sendTimeAsDateTime=false`

The mssql-jdbc driver version I'm using is `6.4.0.jre8`

Other queries using LocalDate work just fine, it's a problem only with LocalTime.
The only thing I can think of to get around this is using a LocalDateTime with dummy date part or storing the time as varchar and using a converter between my class LocalTime and db varchar column but I'd much rather try to have a TIME column

Comment: Try to register org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters as one of the managed JPA classes with your provider. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Are you really sure? Because I'm running Hibernate 5 with the hibernate-java8 dependency and that should be enough, in fact LocalDates and LocalDateTimes are converted properly and I can use those in WHERE clauses just fine. Of all java 8 types only LocalTime is problematic (and only if used in a WHERE clause)